# Why, when specified in Header Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename = hello.xls does the browser not load as a file on disk?

Tags: http

Why, when specified in Response Header Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename = hello.xls does the browser display data as characters in the window rather than downloading as a file to disk?

Complete list:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.2.0 CE GA1 (Mueller / Build 7200 / June 4, 2019)
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.xls
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 06:18:50 GMT
```

Comment: maybe an effect of the overly constraining expires/cache-control header fields? Also, is the behavior the same for all browsers?

Comment: Also, is the behavior the same for all browsers? -Yes

Comment: and did you try without the header fields related to caching?

Comment: Please check your second post of the same question [Why ServletResponseUtil. sendFile sends a file as page content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465593/why-servletresponseutil-sendfile-sends-a-file-as-page-content). For future questions, consider editing and re-tagging a question if you don't get an answer, rather than posting it again with slightly changed wording.