# Why ServletResponseUtil. sendFile sends a file as page content?

Tags: liferay

I want to generate a file and upload it to disk like a file.

I unload as

```
ServletResponseUtil.sendFile(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, fileName, baos.toByteArray(), ContentTypes.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
```

As a result, the file is not uploaded as a file to disk, but to the browser page as

�� ࡱ �; ��    V ���� ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Root Entry   ��������    �FW� Workbook   ������������ !� SummaryInformation(    ����   D

Responce headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.2.0 CE GA1 (Mueller / Build 7200 / June 4, 2019)
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xls"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 46080
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2019 07:21:40 GMT
```

Comment: Are you perhaps uploading a file to the server or downloading it from the server. Because `sendFile`, as the name suggests, is generally used to send a file's contents to the client (i.e. web browser).

Answer (score 0):

That most likely happens because you're running this code within an action- or render-method of your portlet. Portlets render only fragments of HTML pages that will always be embedded in a proper HTML page. If you mock with that by obtaining the HttpServletRequest and (more specifically) HttpServletResponse, you'll just mix the portal's rendered output with your own.

You should use the serveResource method to host your implementation, there you don't even need to revert back to the HttpServletResponse, but can just stream your output to the RenderResponse.

Even if you don't end up with mixed HTML/XLS content but see only the actual XLS output, you might interfere with Liferay's SPA loader, which you can assume knows about expected return values, e.g. when rendering, it expects a HTML portal page, not binary data. That will not be the case when you use the serveResource method, as it is expected to return arbitrary Mimetypes.